# Drawing graphics outside windows using python

Tags: python, graphics, window, draw

I'd like to write a small little program like xpenguins. I feel the original xpenguins is somewhat lacking in performance and compatibility with compiz and unity, so I want to make my own.

My question is this: Which python graphics library will allow me to draw OUTSIDE of windows?

I want to draw 2D transparent graphics without a window border around them on the screen.

Thanks very much,

Barry Smith

Comment: most do I think ... in wx they are called shaped windows ... also the transparency may only work in Windows (not *nix or mac)

Comment: Thanks for the info, thats really helpful. Although I have seen transparency on Unix-based systems before (I use Linux)